# Is there a way to move Advanced Approvals from a sandbox to production?

Tags: advanced-approvals

I've been trying to track down this information, but so far I cannot find a definitive answer. I've been testing an Advanced Approvals process in our full sandbox. I'd like to move my work to production. I have the impression that change sets don't allow me to move my Advanced Approvals work. Does anyone know of any method to move Advanced Approvals? Can I use ANT for this? Or do I simply have to recreate all of my work in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as Advanced Approvals are configured via records in your org, you can't use tools like Change Sets to deploy them.

There are typically a couple of approaches that I've seen with these kind of features within Salesforce (Advanced Approvals is just one example of where we configure via records):

1. **Manual Re-creation:** As you've identified, you can manually re-create the approvals in subsequent environments. This works ok if you've got a smaller set of changes that you need to deploy, but can be time-consuming and result in discrepancies between environments.
2. **DataLoader or Salesforce Data Move Utility (SFDMU):** If you've got External Ids on your records or don't mind using VLOOKUP in Excel you can look to bulk move the configuration records via tools like DataLoader or [SFDMU](https://help.sfdmu.com/). These both work well but generally rely on you making sure you've thought through creating and maintaining external ids on.
3. **Third-Party Tools:** There are a number of third-party tools that have come to market specifically for managing these data driven deployments. I wouldn't go as far as recommending an options, but I'd check out the likes of [Prodly](https://prodly.co/devops/) or [Blue Canvas' CPQ Deployer](https://bluecanvas.io/cpq) tool. If you're using anything like Gearset for managing your other deployments as well then some of those tools now include CPQ deployment tools.